# Can we overwrite NoCahe attribute written in MVC with OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.Net MVC and wrote NoCacheAttribute like this

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then I applied it to my baseController from which all my web controller inherit.

I would like to apply OutputCache to some of my controller methods but since NoCacheAttribute is already applied to the controller class. How can I override NoCache with OutPutCache

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a [IgnoreNoCacheAttribute] which would look like

```
public class IgnoreNoCacheAttribute: Attribute {}
```

Then your NoCacheAttribute becomes

```
  public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            bool ignoreNoCacheAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreNoCacheAttribute), true) ||
                                          filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreNoCacheAttribute), true);

            if (!ignoreNoCacheAttribute)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            }

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Below line is giving me compile time error.                     bool ignoreNoCacheAttribute = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreNoCacheAttribute), true) ||
                                          filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreNoCacheAttribute), true);     ActionDescriptor is not present in filterContext